# Convert MS DOS tree output to graphic

Tags: windows

I am using the tree command to get the subdirectory structure and files of a folder in Windows recursively.

`tree . /f > output.txt`

The redirection to a text file does not produce a very aesthetically pleasing representation of my directory structure and its contents.

Is there a way to pragmatically generate a graphical representation of a particular directory and it's sub directories and files?  Ideally it would be a "weblike" diagram with nodes and connections.

Comment: Define "aesthetically pleasing"

Comment: Have you tried WinDirStat? It has some exporting options (I might be thinking the wrong application, but I'm at work and can't get to my personal computer at the moment). There are likely. programs specifically designed to do what your talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `/a` switch to use normal ASCII characters instead of extended characters to create the output.

```
tree . /f /a > output.txt
```

This changes the output text in a normal plain text file from:

```
C:.
³   New Microsoft Word Document.docx
³   New Text Document.txt
³   output.txt
³   Test Doc.docm
³   
ÀÄÄÄNew folder
        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
```

To

```
C:.
|   New Microsoft Word Document.docx
|   New Text Document.txt
|   output.txt
|   Test Doc.docm
|   
\---New folder
        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
```